# Link or extension to assign a certain value to a chrome flag (Force Dark Mode for Web Contents)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, url, flag

"Force Dark Mode for Web Contents : Enabled" works fine in a lot of sites. But when it doesn't, I want to switch the flag to "Disabled" or "Default" with a click of a button (without having to access chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark and changing the value in the dropdown).
Is there a way to have a bookmark or an extension that can switch a flag's value?

Comment: [Dark Mode - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj?hl=en)?